Python Pycharm virtualenv cant add new virtualenv
I made some tests with multiple virtualenv Environment in Pycharm Professional Version 2024.1.1.
Now im stuck with the Problem, that I cant make a new Virtualenv anymore, because all i get is this error message:

There is no env folder inside this directory or in any project directory.
When i press the Existing Environment, there is no environment to select:

What did i miss at this point?
What I already tried:

Use the invalidate caches inside PyCharm
Searched inside .idea/workspace for references to an env
Close every PyCharm instance and restart the Computer

I expected to be able now at this point to make a new virtualenv.
I tried some comments from this post but this did not work at all.

If i install everything manually and select them, then it works fine. Just not possible in pycharm
